# JxBrowser - Save cached image

Tags: jxbrowser

Is there a way to save a cached image from a loaded page?  I would like to be able to right click on a image and have a option to "Save image as...".  I know I could extract the image url and download it but if the image changes I won't be able to get the current one displayed on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Right now JxBrowser API doesn't provide functionality that allows saving images via approach you are requesting.
This feature will be implemented in one of the next JxBrowser versions. I will let you know when updated build with the feature is available for download.

Comment: Is this coming soon?

Comment: It's hard to determine terms because this issue doesn't have high priority. I suppose that we might start working on this issue not earlier than this summer.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try this solution:

```
NetworkService networkService = browser.getContext().getNetworkService();
networkService.setNetworkDelegate(new DefaultNetworkDelegate() {
@Override
public void onDataReceived(DataReceivedParams params) {

        if (params.getMimeType().equals("image/png")) { 
            byte[] img = params.getData();
            if(img!=null){
                ByteArrayToImage("png",img);
                System.out.println("PNG image data = " + Arrays.toString(img));
            }
        }
        if (params.getMimeType().equals("image/jpeg") || params.getMimeType().equals("image/jpg")) { 
            byte[] img = params.getData();
            if(img!=null){
                ByteArrayToImage("jpg",img);
                System.out.println("jpeg image data = " + Arrays.toString(img));
            }
        }
    }

});
```

With utility image routine:

```
public static void ByteArrayToImage(String imageType, byte[] data) {
  ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
  BufferedImage bImage2;
  Random rn = new Random();
    int random = rn.nextInt(100) + 1;
    try {
        bImage2 = ImageIO.read(bis);            
        ImageIO.write(bImage2, imageType, new File("D://tmp//output"+random+"." + imageType) );
        System.out.println("image created");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }      
}
```